# IF statement using procedure parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I’m wondering if it’s technically possible to use procedure parameters in IF statement or how to solve this problem in different manner.

Situation description:
I have a procedure within other procedure where arguments of inner procedure are parameters of outer procedure. I would
like to use parameters of inner procedure within it’s body in IF statement eg: IF parameter1 OR parameter2 OR parameter3 IS NOT NULL THEN. . It’s worth to be mentioned that all parameters of outer procedure have to be DEFAULT NULL. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Is it a correct syntax for such a statement?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do like this :

```
--first procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(f_name varchar2 ,sal NUMBER )
IS 
BEGIN 

p2(f_name,sal);

END;

--second procedure

CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE p2(f_name varchar2 ,sal NUMBER )
IS 
BEGIN 

IF f_name IS NOT NULL OR sal IS NOT NULL
THEN 
dbms_output.put_line(f_name ||'   '||sal);
END IF;

END;
```

then call the first procedure :

```
BEGIN 
    p1( 'john',null );
END;
```